# How can I get a list of legal ARM opcodes from gcc (or elsewhere)?

Tags: gcc, arm, llvm

I'd like to generate pseudo-random ARM instructions. Via assembler directives, I can tell gcc what mode I'm in, and it will complain if I try a set of opcodes and operands that's not legal in that mode, so it must have some internal listing of what can be done in which mode. Where does that live? Would it be easier to extract that info from LLVM?

Is this question "not even wrong"? Should I try a different approach entirely?

Comment: just out of curiosity: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Mat, I think [this](https://github.com/dwelch67/thumbulator) ARM thumb emulator is pretty cool, and I want to try writing something similar in another language as a way to learn a new language. I want to test my emulator against David's as an easy way to check that I'm not doing anything wrong. I could just feed them both the same random bit strings, but I'd like something slightly more directed.

Comment: throwing "random" instructions at them doesn't make much sens IMO: if the two emulators do something different, how will you know which one is right if you don't know what's supposed to happen either?

Comment: Shouldn't you look that up on the ARM ARM (ARM Architecture Reference Manual)?

Comment: I'll look in the manual, which is what I'm doing for the implementation in the first place. Taken in its most general form, your comment sounds like "why bother testing? You won't know if it's your tests that are broken or your program".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, this is actually really easy to do from arm.md and and constraints.md in gcc/config/arm/. I probably spent more time answering asking this question and answering comments for it than I did figuring this out. Turns out I just need to look for 'TARGET_THUMB1', until I get around to implementing thumb2.

Answer (score 1):

For the ARM family the buck stops at the ARM ARM (ARM Architectural Reference Manual).  There is an ARM instruction set section and a Thumb instruction set section.  Within both each instruction tells you what generation (ARMvX where X is some number like 4 (arm7), or 5 (arm9 time frame) ,etc).  Since the opcode and pseudo code is listed for each instruction you should be able to figure out what is a real instruction and, if any, are syntax to save typing on another (push and pop for example).

With the Cortex-m3 and thumb2 in particular you also need to look at the TRM (Technical Reference Manual) as well.  ARM has, I forget the name, a universal syntax they are trying to use that should work on both Thumb and ARM.  For example on an ARM you have three register instructions:

```
add r1,r1,r2
```

In thumb there are only two register operations

```
add r1,r2
```

The desire basically is to meet in the middle or I would say more accurately to encourage ARM assemblers to parse Thumb instructions and encode them with the equivalent ARM instruction without complaining.  This may have started with thumb and not thumb2, I have always separated the two syntaxes in my code until recently (and I still generally use ARM syntax for ARM and Thumb for Thumb).

And then yes you have to see what the specific implementation of the assembler tool is, in your case binutils.  And it sounds like you have found the binutils/gnu secret decoder ring.